# Why one needs quotes other doesn't

Tags: mysql

I have 2 values in an update query both are integers. When I try:

```
$sql = "UPDATE album SET mod=1, sid=$s WHERE id=$a";
```

it does not work. When I change it to:

```
$sql = "UPDATE album SET `mod`=1, sid=$s WHERE id=$a";
```

it works.

```
$b = 1;
$sql = "UPDATE album SET mod=$b, sid=$s WHERE id=$a";
```

is not working either.

So why does the variable mod need quotes but sid doesn't?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html `mod`

Comment: What is the error when it is "not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"mod" in this case will most likely refer to the modulus operator (remainder when dividing). So mod is reserved for the operator MOD(), how ever, having `mod` will not interpret it as an use of operator. Even if `mod` works I would advise you to chose another name which is not conflicting with a reserved keyword.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Answer (score 0):

The "variable" `mod` does not need backquotes. The **function name** `MOD` does. As do all other function names, keywords, and so on.